# How do I start a timer after a button on another page has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I have a few questions here that I want to put together.

1. How do I start a countdown timer after a button **on another page** has been clicked?
2. After the timer has been clicked, how do I prevent it from resetting when the page has been refreshed? (I found examples of using cookies etc but I couldn't find a way to add them into my code below).
3. The timer will only be stopped when a button has been pressed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Timer extends Component {
    
    state = {
        minutes: 1,
        seconds: 0,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            const { seconds, minutes } = this.state

            if (seconds > 0) {
                this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
                    seconds: seconds - 1
                }))
            }
            if (seconds === 0) {
                if (minutes === 0) {
                    clearInterval(this.myInterval)
                } else {
                    this.setState(({ minutes }) => ({
                        minutes: minutes - 1,
                        seconds: 59
                    }))
                }
            } 
        }, 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.myInterval)
    }

    render() {
        const { minutes, seconds } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                { minutes === 0 && seconds === 0
                    ? <h1></h1>
                    : <h1>Timer is counting: {minutes}:{seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}</h1>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Timer
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: So you are on a page B, you press a button. And in a page A, a timer is triggered ?

Comment: Use redux, when button clicked store date time when button pressed and wherever you want timer logic check if that redux state has date time set then start timer and also calculate elapsed time by comparing button pressed date time and current date time.

Comment: Write simple Browser extension which is pretty easy even for beginners (lots of tutorials) or use something like Toggle (not exactly what you are looking for but close enough).

Comment: @MarcCharpentier precisely yes! on page B when you press the button, the button brings you to page A where the timer starts counting down.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a time for countdown

`const TIMER_TIME = 120; // time of the timer in seconds`

2. Start timeout by saving a time of timer start

`localStorage.setItem('timer-start', new Date().getTime()); // can be called from any page, trigger by any thing`

3. Handle the timeleft in the component

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.calculateTimer();
    }
    calculateTimer = () => {
      const startTime = localStorage.getItem('timer-start'); // get data of time start
      if(!startTime) return {seconds:0,minutes:0};
      const timeLeft = TIMER_TIME - (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000; // timeleft = timer time -time over
      if(timeLeft <= 0) { // reset timer if its finish
        localStorage.removeItem('timer-start');
        clearTimeout(this.myInterval);
        return {seconds:0,minutes:0}
      }
      return {minutes: Math.floor(timeLeft/60), seconds: Math.floor(timeLeft%60)}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.myInterval = setInterval(() => this.setState(this.calculateTimer()), 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.myInterval)
    }

    render() {
        const { minutes, seconds } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                { minutes === 0 && seconds === 0
                    ? <h1></h1>
                    : <h1>Timer is counting: {minutes}:{seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}</h1>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```